# Joining 5 tables in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

So here's a challenge. I have a webpage that needs to show data from 5 different tables in a database. Here's the query:

```
'SELECT ORGANIZATIONS.ORG_NAME, ORG_SECTIONS.SectionName, ATTORNEYS.NAME, ATTORNEYS.LASTNAME, ATTORNEYS.EMAIL, ATTORNEYS.TEL, ATTY_TITLES.ATT_TITLE, FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS.PRACTICE_GRP
         FROM (ORGANIZATIONS INNER JOIN (Org_Sec_Atty INNER JOIN ATTORNEYS ON Org_Sec_Atty.Atty_ID = ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID) ON ORGANIZATIONS.ID = Org_Sec_Atty.OrgID) INNER JOIN ORG_SECTIONS ON Org_Sec_Atty.SecID = ORG_SECTIONS.ID
         WHERE ATTORNEYS.LASTNAME LIKE @LASTNAME;'
```

The 5 tables are Org_Sec_Atty, ORGANIZATIONS, ORG_SECTIONS, ATTORNEYS, ATTY_TITLES, and FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS. First, I didn't come up with the table names, lol.

Second, ATTORNEYS is the table that has ATTY_ID, TITLE_ID, PRACTICE_GRP_ID, which is what I'm sure I need to join to FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS and ATTY_TITLE, and then it needs to connect with the Org_Sec_Atty and ORG_SECTIONS table.

I already have a page where the three tables ATTORNEYS, Org_Sec_Atty, and ORG_SECTIONS are joined by the JOIN statement you see up there. I'm trying to figure out where the other INNER JOIN statements would go and in what order.

It seems like I need to replace "ATTORNEYS" in the "Org_Sec_Atty INNER JOIN ATTORNEYS" with the subordinate INNER JOIN statements, but, again, I'm not sure of the order. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified foreign keys on last two tables. Change appropriately if necessary:

```
SELECT  ORGANIZATIONS.ORG_NAME ,
        ORG_SECTIONS.SectionName ,
        ATTORNEYS.NAME ,
        ATTORNEYS.LASTNAME ,
        ATTORNEYS.EMAIL ,
        ATTORNEYS.TEL ,
        ATTY_TITLES.ATT_TITLE ,
        FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS.PRACTICE_GRP
FROM    (((( ORGANIZATIONS
          INNER JOIN Org_Sec_Atty ON ORGANIZATIONS.ID = Org_Sec_Atty.OrgID)
          INNER JOIN ATTORNEYS ON Org_Sec_Atty.Atty_ID = ATTORNEYS.ATTY_ID) 
          INNER JOIN ORG_SECTIONS ON Org_Sec_Atty.SecID = ORG_SECTIONS.ID)
          INNER JOIN ATTY_TITLES ON ORG_SECTIONS.ATTY_ID = ATTY_TITLES.ID)
          INNER JOIN FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS ON ATTY_TITLES.FIRM_ID = FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS.ID

WHERE   ATTORNEYS.LASTNAME LIKE @LASTNAME;
```

Comment: Okay, so this seems to be a good start, however, there are no FKs tying FIRM_PRACTICE_GRPS and ATTY_TITLES together. The ATTORNEYS Table is what they can each relate to though.

Comment: And I should say that those tables shouldn't relate to each other either. It wouldn't make sense in the scheme of the database.